# What does "to invite oneself" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I usually have lunch alone but yesterday I asked my colleague to join their lunch by saying

> "I will join your lunch."

(I usually join them one or twice a week.)

Then one of them told the other guy in the group that

> "XXX (my name) invited himself today."

Is it the same as saying "he will join us today?" or does it imply something?

Comment: Normally, it's considered impolite to invite yourself to something; you should typically wait until you are invited. So *that guy* was gently pointing out that you were a bit presumptuous and essentially *told* them that you were going with them instead of being asked.  He may have also been making a point to *the other guy* that it's not his fault you're here- he didn't invite you, you invited yourself.  However, if you *usually* go with them once or twice a week, and if they usually ask you if you want to go with them on those occasions it's probably not too bad that you invited yourself.

Comment: To follow up on what Jim said, perhaps this colleague was gently teasing you or maybe he was irritated by your self-invite and considered you to be rude. It could have been said in jest, or it was a quip, a piece of wit. How your colleague spoke, his tone of voice and body language would have conveyed more meaning than just his bare words reported here.

Comment: In the US, it's acceptable to invite yourself occasionally by asking: *May I join you?* or *Do you mind if I come along?* It's considered more polite than just announcing your intentions. Then be sure to reciprocate.

Comment: With the basic meaning of 'invite', it's probably impossible to 'invite oneself' as one doesn't really have the authority. But, as the previous comments say, this is a well-established and quite acceptable secondary usage.

Comment: As Mari-Lou says, it was very likely said **completely in jest**.  If the guy "meant it" -- i.e., he was **actually** being rude to you, it would be in fact be "very rude indeed." Does that make sense?  Note that if the guy "meant it" (ie, he was genuinely being rude) everyone around you would have been completely shocked.  But it is very, very likely the guy was just kidding, just a passing comment.  Just to be clear you should never ever say this to anyone.  You could say this **about yourself** jokingly. (so, "Hey guys, mind if I invite myself along??")

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record,

```
So, you invited yourself along today?
```

would be a very, very rude thing to say (ie, the prelude to a fist-fight), **IF** the person said it completely "straight", i.e., they meant it.

It is extremely likely the person said it purely jokingly.

{Conversely if, in fact, the person "really meant it", you'll have to beat the hell out of him.  :) }

Note too that it would be perfectly OK and funny to say this **about yourself** - so "Hey guys, I'll invite myself along today!"

Personally, I would recommend completely avoiding this phrase. It's one of those things that (IMO) is just "not that funny".

Comment: isn't this more ELL by the way?